# Google Maps API zoom without tiling

Tags: google-maps-api-3

I'm using the Google Maps API to browse my own maps. The problem is, I only have one rather small resolution file, that I wanna display fully at level 0, which means it's not gonna get any more accurate when zooming. I still wanna be able to zoom though, by just enlarging the image. This would be useful for the markers and polygons I intend to draw on it, as they could be viewed in larger detail.

I could just create dummy tiles, that show no higher resolution than the original, but that seems like a roundabout solution that would do nothing but create more unnecessary server requests for the map files, as well as more traffic.

The problem seems to be the `getTileUrl()` function, as it is required. I can't think of a clever way to abuse it either, to only show different sections of the same map.

I know it already supports image enlarging, as you can observe the effect when you zoom in. The question is, if you could make that effect permanent somehow, and not make the image disappear if no new image is provided.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Suggestion:**

Use the ImageMapType only to hide tiles at all(therefore let `getTileUrl()` simply return `null`)

For your own map don't use tiles, create a [GroundOverlay](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/overlays#GroundOverlays) instead.

Comment: Worked like a charm. Well, or rather it would, if it wasn't for an unrelated issue, but I'll post about that later if I don't manage to fix it. Thanks.